# how to erase with iterator for std::list template

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, arraylist, c++14

I'm trying to understand how the iterator works.

I have build the following code:

```
list<Bucket<Key,Val>> *array;

template<typename Key, typename Val>
class Bucket
{
public:
    Bucket(Key key, Val value)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
    }

    ~Bucket(){}

    const Key getKey() const
    {
        return key;
    }

    const Val getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }

private:
    Key key;
    Val value;
};
```

After inserting a bucket in one of the lists, I would like to do 2 actions at least:
Find and Remove.

I can look for a given value with this code:

```
    int entryNum = HashFunc()(key);

    for(auto i: array[entryNum % capacity])
    {
        if(MatchFunc(i.getKey(),key)())
        {
            value = i.getValue();
        }
    }
```

But I can't seem to delete an item by adding something like
i = array[entryNum % capacity].erase(i);
or with remove.
But if i do this, it works:

```
    int entryNum = HashFunc()(key);
    typename list<Bucket<Key,Val>>::iterator it;

    for(auto i: array[entryNum % capacity])
    {
        ++testcounter;
        if(MatchFunc(i.getKey(),key)())
        {
            value = i.getValue();
        }
    }

    for (it=array[entryNum % capacity].begin(); it!= array[entryNum % capacity].end(); ++it)
    {
        if(testcounter!=0) --testcounter;
        else
        {
            array[entryNum % capacity].erase(it);
            return htKeyFound;
        }
    }
```

This is obviously not ideal, I would like to NOT go twice over the same list + keeping a counter for it. But I can't seem to join them into one.
When I try to access the it.getKey() it obviously doesn't work and crests a compilation error.
Any advice about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Range `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates over the *values* inside the container.

The [`std::list::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) function expects an *iterator* and not a value.

---

And you don't need two loops, you can dereference an iterator to get the value it "points" to:

```
int entryNum = HashFunc()(key);

auto& list_ref = array[entryNum % capacity];
for(auto it = list_ref.begin(); it != list_ref.end(); ++it)
{
    if(MatchFunc(it->getKey(),key)())
    {
        value = it->getValue();
        list_ref.erase(it);
        return htKeyFound;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well dude, it worked !! :) ty you very much, tho i will mention the ref line is 'auto& list_ref'. other wise it doesn't compile - ty again